# $n$-th Neumann eigenspace of Laplacian operator $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}_+$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

It's well know that $n$-th eigenspace of Laplacian operator $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}| |x|^2= 1 \}$ is generated by harmonics homgeneous polynomial of degree $n$. When we work with the hemisphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}_+ = \{ x = (x_1,\dots,x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^{d}| |x|^2= 1 \mbox{ and } x_d \geq 0 \}$, what subset of set of harmonics homgeneous polynomial of degree $n$ generates $n$-th Neumann eigenspace of Laplacian operator $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}_+$ ? 
$n$-th Neumann eigenspace of Laplacian operator $\Delta$ $:=$ linear space formed by all the eigenfunctions of $\Delta$ which satisfy to Neumann boundary condition.

Comment: Will this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Higher_dimensions) help?